# How to apply IF logic during stream pipeline calculation?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a code like this. But it looks a bit ugly

```
Set<String> strings= new HashSet(Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3" ));
Optional.of(strings.stream()
                .filter(myMap::containsKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get)))
                .map(stringListMap -> stringListMap.isEmpty() ? null : stringListMap)
                .orElse(myMap)
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(...)
                ...
```

Is there way to avoid collection in the middle of pipeline ?

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get))` won't return null even if your stream is empty. So `Optional` doesn't make a difference here, at least as implemented. Is your intention to fall back to `myMap` when the first stream is empty?

Comment: @ernest_k good catch - you are right. Updated. but my code became even more ugly

Comment: @Michael I am really sorry for that. Updated.

Comment: So the logic is "filter map by set, or fallback to full map if intersection is empty"?

Comment: @Kayaman SET is user generated. It might be empty and might be not empty but those values could be absent in the map "myMap".  In case if we don't have any matched values in Map we should use the whole map myMap in cosequent calculations.

Does it make sense for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not adding much here - very similar to Michael's answer. But this avoids creating streams out of both `myMap` and `strings`.

```
Map<String, Object> mappedValues = strings.stream()
     .filter(myMap::containsKey)
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get)));

(mappedValues.isEmpty()
    ? myMap
    : mappedValues).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the more imperative solution is actually more readable here.

```
Map<String, Object> actualMap = myMap; // equiv. to your .orElse(myMap)
if (myMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(strings::contains)) {
    actualMap = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), myMap::get));
}
actualMap.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(...)
```

Java's a nice language because it allows you to be pragmatic about when you apply functional ideas. Don't feel like you have to use them all the time.

Comment: This option is clear. I just wanted to make sure that there are no any beatifull functional construction for such case.

Comment: Java is not a functional language. It's not beautiful when people cram together huge stream operations because they think "I need to get this done in a one-liner". It makes the code unreadable for Java programmers and unreadable for functional programmers.

Comment: @Kayaman partially agree but java is also a functuinal lang since java 8 when lambda was introduced. At least streams are functional.

Comment: @gstackoverflow just because Java has some functional "flavor" doesn't make Java a FP language. Try telling a Haskell programmer that Java is a functional language, and see what they think. Use the right tool, not just "use a single stream to do everything".

Comment: @Kayaman I can't agre more. But if you are not sure -threre is nothing bad if you ask, Isn't it ? in some cases Optional is really much more convenient than if-else

Comment: I think the definition is somewhat debatable. I wouldn't personally define Java as a functional language, but rather a language in which you can write code in a functional *style*. The value in any multi-paradigm language is that it lets you pick and choose the best bits from each depending what you're doing. The downside is that writing code within any one specific paradigm is likely to be worse than in a language which is rigidly built around that one idea.

Comment: BTW @Michael you lost this line *.filter(myMap::containsKey)*

Comment: @Michael In some cases  it is hard to choose the best paradigm. Listening developers from comminity help to make a correct decision.

Comment: Depending on the actual scenario, I’d go even a step further, `Map<String, Object> actualMap = new HashMap<>(myMap); actualMap.keySet().retainAll(strings); if(actualMap.isEmpty()) actualMap = myMap;` Yes, that’s no “functional style” at all, but using the power of the good old Collection API.

Comment: @Holger good catch but it creates additional map even if we don;t need it. In my case map size is 10mb

Comment: @gstackoverflow and how big is your `strings` set?

Comment: @Holger it is much much smaller

Comment: @gstackoverflow then, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70082626/2711488) is preferable, as it only streams over the smaller set. Depending on what is actually happening in the subsequent `.flatMap(...)`, you probably don’t need to produce a `Map` at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's a sort of a late answer, but the following solution does not use `Optional` and does not create a mapping if no key from `strings` exists in `myMap` at the cost of duplicate running the stream on the smaller `strings` set:

```java
(strings.stream().anyMatch(myMap::containsKey)
    ? strings.stream()
             .filter(myMap::containsKey)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, myMap::get))
    : myMap
)
.entrySet().stream()
           .flatMap()
```